# Separate class usage and design

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

This is a basic question, but I have no idea how to set this class up.  I had a c# code file that was just getting too big, so I wanted to start breaking it up into smaller chunks.

So I took 3 methods out, and put it in this class called **Events**.

Now if my ***main class*** needs the methods in this new class, do I just call it like this?

I did try this, and it works.  But it seems as if I'm not really saving any space by doing this.

```
IEnumerable<EngineSchema> thisWeeksParts =
                          Events.WeeklyPartsList(engineCat, startDay, endDay)
```

Thanks!

Here is the new class:

```
public static class Events
{
    public static IEnumerable<EngineSchema> WeeklyPartsList(IEnumerable<EngineClass> engineCategory, DateTime startDay,
        DateTime endDay)
    {
        var EngineParts =
            engineCategory.SelectMany(e => e.Pages)
                .Where(c => c.StartDateTime >= startDay & c.EndDateTime <= endDay);
        return EngineParts;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<EngineClass> ClassOfEngine(int EngineSpecGroupID)
    {
        return Repository.Query()
            .Where(c => c.VehicleGroup.Any(cg => searchParts.Contains(EngineSpecGroupID)));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<EngineSchema> GetEngineList(int engineYear, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return WeeklyPartsList(ClassOfEngine(engineYear), startDate, endDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it.  What's the problem?  Did you even try it?  Or are you just asking us if it will work before you even tried it?

Comment: I did try it and it works.  But it seems cumbersome and I'm not sure if I'm saving any space/time by doing this.

Comment: This looks like it should work fine, honestly. Splitting up your code into distinct parts helps reduce the clutter in each file and can clarify what each part of the system does and what responsibilities each part has.

Comment: Well, by splitting things up, you're getting closer to adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and Separation of Concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if my main class needs the methods in this new class, do I just call it like this? [...]

Although the "pure" static syntax works fine, it may be slightly more convenient to switch to an extension syntax:

```
public static IEnumerable<EngineSchema> WeeklyPartsList(this IEnumerable<EngineClass> engineCategory, DateTime startDay, DateTime endDay) ...
//                                                      ^^^^
```

Now you can call your method as follows:

```
IEnumerable<EngineSchema> thisWeeksParts = engineCat.WeeklyPartsList(startDay, endDay);
```

or

```
foreach (var part in Events.ClassOfEngine(123).WeeklyPartsList(startDay, endDay)) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: wait, how does that work?  The method needs the IEnumerable<EngineClass> engineCategory passed into it as a parameter.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Adding `this` in front of the first parameter lets you choose between `Events.Foo(firstArg, secondArg)` and `firstArg.Foo(secondArg)` ways of making a call, with `Events` portion being implied. This is a 100% compiler trick - the IL code the compiler generates is exactly the same. The compiler takes the "target" of invocation, i.e. `firstArg`, and sticks it back as the first parameter into the call to `Events.Foo` method.

Answer (score -3):

Yes that is how you call static methods within a static class.  If the size of the code file was your only concern, I would have gone with just creating a new one and using a [partial class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: This is a non-answer.

Comment: better than encouraging static class use because the file size is too big.